Almost sure convergence implies almost surely bounded for all sufficiently large n?
Let $\{X_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of random variables.
In the book ''Asymptotic Theory for Econometricians'' by Halbert
White it is stated that if $X_{n}$ converges almost surely to $0$,
then $\left|X_{n}\right|$ is also almost surely bounded for all sufficiently
large $n$.
That is, there exist $K<\infty$ and $m<\infty$
such that
\begin{equation}
P\left(\left|X_{n}\right|<K\text{ for all }n\geq m\right)=1.
\end{equation}
However, I can't see how this can be universally true. For instance, consider
$$
X_{n}=\begin{cases}
n^{3} & \text{with probability }n^{-2}\\
0 & \text{with probability }1-n^{-2}.
\end{cases}
$$
Here, $X_{n}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely, but I don't see how such an almost sure bound
could exist since $P\left(\left|X_{n}\right|<K\text{ for all }n\geq m\right)$
will always be smaller than $1$ for $K<\infty$ and $m<\infty$.
The existence of such a bound also seems to not align with this definition of almost
sure convergence (to $0$):
For every $K>0$,
$$
\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}P\left(\left|X_{n}\right|<K\text{ for all }n\geq m\right)=1.
$$

This may be about language and in particular "all sufficiently large $n$" and "almost surely bounded".  Illustrating this with your nice example, the number of $n$ with $X_n \not=0$ is almost surely finite; if that is finite then there will be an $m$ for which for all $n >m$ you have $X_n =0$, and for all $n$ you have $|X_n| \lt m^3+1$ so it is bounded.  But you do not know $m$ or $K$ in advance.

That actually does make a lot of sense. Thank you!

To repeat my comment as an answer:
This may be about language and in particular "all sufficiently large $n$" and "almost surely bounded".
Illustrating this with your nice example, the number of $n$ with $X_n \not=0$ is almost surely finite; if that is finite then there will be an $m$ for which for all $n >m$ you have $X_n =0$, and for all $n$ you have $|X_n| \lt m^3+1$ so it is bounded.
But you do not know $m$ or $K$ in advance, and that may have caused the confusion.
